# Does .wrap( ) cancel the wrappers style properties?

Tags: jquery, html, css, text-align

I have a button:

```
var button = ($('<button>', {
            "id": "jspsych-free-sort-done-btn",
            "class": "jspsych-free-sort",
            "html": "Done",
            ...
}));
```

that I want to center. Someone on stackoverflow suggested using .wrap() to add a wrapper div but this doesn't seem to be centering the button:

```
button.wrap("<div style='text-align:center'> </div>");
```

Does .wrap() cancel the wrapper's style properties? And if so how to I center my button? Thanks!

Comment: Center your button in what HTML context?  A button is an inline element so it goes inline with the other content around it.  You have to show the surrounding and containing HTML for us to have any idea how to solve this.

Comment: how is the button added to the dom

Comment: I can't even get it to center when it is the only element.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gsakm90r/1/ - not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gsakm90r/2/ & http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gsakm90r/3/ - working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible issue is with how & when you are wrapping the element and then how the button is added to the dom.

If you are wrapping the button before adding it to the dom and then is adding the button to the dom directly then the wrapped div will not get added to the dom, so the wrapping will not have any effect.

So wrap the button, then add the button's parent element to the dom like

```js
var button = ($('<button>', {
  "id": "jspsych-free-sort-done-btn",
  "class": "jspsych-free-sort",
  "html": "Done"
}));

button.wrap("<div style='text-align:center'> </div>");

button.parent().appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could give your wrap a width, like `width:100%; text-align:center;` while I would as well add on `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to my button's style.

Answer (score 0):

`wrap()` creates a parent element for `button` object. You can selet it using `parent()`. Another way is to wrap after appending using ID.

```js
var button = $('<button>', {
    "id": "jspsych-free-sort-done-btn",
    "class": "jspsych-free-sort",
    "html": "Done"
}).wrap("<div style='text-align:center'> </div>").parent();
button.appendTo('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```